# can i use Spring framework for developing JSP application?

Tags: spring

I have Eclipse-EE 3.6 IDE...I want to develop a Web Application using JSP and Servlet.

I plan to develop this application using Spring framework.

is it possible...can i use Spring framework for developing JSP application?

can you provide some Tutorials for JSP Application development using spring for beginners.

Comment: Be a little more specific (as spring covers quite a wide area). You intend to use just the Spring core module (IoC) in a Servlet + JSP web application ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spring MVC. Try following tutorials:

http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/
http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-mvc-tutorial-1.html
http://maestric.com/doc/java/spring

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. JSP is a standard view technology for spring-mvc. I'd recommend the official [spring-mvc documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would say, that this is one of the most done use case for Spring.

Anyway: I strongly recommend to use [STS (SpringSource Tool Suite)](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts), it is free and based on Eclipse 3.6 Java EE, but provides additional Spring features. For example the some templates for Spring Projects (new Project/SpringSource Tool Suite/Spring Template Project).

And one very interesting Feature: Task Base Tutorials. They are great if you want to lern form an example: Dashbord/Tutorials/